# Meaning of “as soon as school was out for the day”

Tags: meaning

> As soon as school was out for the day, they always came to play there.

What should I understand when I read this expression: ”as soon as school was out for the day”

Comment: What do you understand?  Is the expression "As soon as"  familiar to you?  Is the expression "school was out"?  Do you understand "school was out for the day"?    Can you retype the text in the image (as images can't be searched, indexed or used by screen readers)

Answer (score 1):

It means the children's time of attending school for the the day has ended. It is said that "school has let out", or "school is out".
School can be "out for the summer" when the school year has ended. It is out for the day when the school day has ended.

So, the sentence means that the children came to play right after they were released from school.

Comment: School being "out" is a mainly US usage.